# HAProxy with 'backup' failure

Tags: linux, load-balancing, haproxy

I have a simple configuration of 2 MySQL being load balanced by HAProxy. For an unfortunate reason I need to use them in Passive\Active mode. So I thought I'd configure one DB as  'backup' and go to sleep. But I was wrong. Whenever I add the 'backup' to the server line HAProxy throws a communication link error (essentially saying 'no DB available" (with the 'backup' it works great). It just doesnt consider that server as a valid option any more...

I have tried this configuration:

> listen  mysql 10.0.0.109:3307
>
> ```
>     mode tcp
>     balance roundrobin
>     option httpchk
>     server db01 10.0.0.236:3306
>     server db02 10.0.0.68:3306 backup
> ```

and also this configuration:

> frontend mysql_proxy
>
> ```
>     bind 10.0.0.109:3307
>     default_backend mysql
> ```
>
> backend mysql
>
> ```
> mode tcp
> balance roundrobin
> option httpchk
> server db01 10.0.0.236:3306  
> server db02 10.0.0.68:3306 backup
> ```

Nothing worked!

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4):

Addressing the original question as to why the example does not work there are 2 things which stand out:

1. the `check` keyword is not added to the `server` declarations, which tells haproxy to use the health check directive on this server.
2. the `httpchk` keyword is best used together with a `port` on the `server` directive to define where the HTTP health check service is running. This method assumes you've setup a service somewhere that reports the health of the master.

For example, I think something like this would work (untested)

```
backend mysql
  mode tcp
  balance roundrobin
  option  httpchk GET /master_status
  server db01 10.0.0.236:3306 weight 100 check port 3305 inter 1s rise 3 fall 2
  server db02 10.0.0.68:3306 weight 100 check port 3305 inter 1s rise 3 fall 2 backup
```

In this example, haproxy will query the `/master_status` url on port 3305 on each `server`. If  the server returns a 2xx status code, the backend will be available through haproxy. Otherwise, it will be offline.

To solve the problem of the health check service, you can use the rubygem `mysql_health`. You would run this service on each database server that participates in the haproxy cluster.

https://github.com/osterman/mysql_health

To start the health check service, you would run something like:

```
/usr/bin/mysql_health --server:pid-file=/var/run/mysql_health.pid \
                      --log:file /var/log/mysql_health.log \
                      --server:daemonize \
                      --server:port 3305 \
                      --check:master \
                      --check:database mysql
```

There are many more command line options available. Use the `--help` argument for more details.

Answer (score 0):

what haproxy version are you using ?, if you are using version 1.4, it's support mysql health check "option mysql-check" e.g:

```
mode tcp
balance roundrobin
option tcplog
option mysql-check user haproxy
server svr1 svr1:3306 check inter 2s rise 2 fall 2
server svr2 svr2:3306 check backup inter 2s rise 2 fall 2
```

my setup, it's working fine with mysql master - master (using active standy).

Comment: I have the latest version (1.4.8). For some reason it just refuses to accept the 'backup' keyword. What version are you using?

Comment: haproxy-1.4.15, are you sure 1.4.8 ?, the latest is 1.4.18 based on http://haproxy.1wt.eu/#down. could you remove "option httpchk" ?